# Which modeler should I use for eventual libGDX rendering?

Tags: rendering, libgdx, blender

I found a couple of good looking .3DS models I would like to tweak and render with libGDX.
I am embarassingly new to this.
"Blender" is doing a nice job at loading .3DS files, and can export to OBJ format.
Now, libGDX states that OBJ support is `Only intended for testing basic models/meshes and educational usage`
Hence my question, which (free) modeler should I be using to create textured objects that I will eventually load+render with libGDX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Blender (and pretty much any other 3d model software). But you should export your models to **.fbx** instead (that format is supported in most 3d model softwares).

Then use [Fbx-Conv](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/fbx-conv/) to convert it to **.g3db** (or **.g3dj** for testing purposes).

Reference: [Importing Blender models in LibGDX](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX)

Comment: Worked as advertised :) Thanks